# How can I access the Music folder?

Tags: windows-7, music

In Windows 7 the Music library includes a number of folder, one of them is called My Music. The My Music folder itself is located in c:\users\USERNAME. If I open the folder I see all my music files that are there. The problem is just that if I open a command prompt and list all folders in C:\users\USERNAME\ I can see that the folder is actually called "Music", not "My Music". Also if I list all files in the Music folder, there are files that are not music files, and theses files are invisible in Windows Explorer. How can I access this folder in its entirety from Windows explorer??? Can I tell Windows that this folder is not a Music folder?

Comment: Are you trying to turn your Music library into another type of library?  Do you know that you can create new libraries?  I imagine the reason you're seeing `My Music` and `Music` is a bug from a design decision to keep backwards compatibility with older software, where it was always known as `My Music`.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please post the output of directory listing for the Music Folder? And also a screenshot of your "My Music" folder.

It seems what you looking at are the system hidden files. They tell Windows about a variety of things and tell explorer how to customize the folder according to its content.

You can enable viewing these files in explorer by editing this registry entry:

```
\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\ShowSuperHidden
```

and set the value to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Either look via libaries\mymusic or via (as you have) c:\users etc  or documents\my music\ (I can't test, not near W7 machine)